# My Vue 2 Vite does not recognize my subdomain 'foo.example.st' in the Request URL

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, vite, laravel-mix

My app with subdomain is a dockerized Laravel application and I want to "reference" it in a new dockerzied vite Vue 2 application, so I've doing the following in the vite.config.js:

I've tried the following:

```
server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://foo.example.st',
        changeOrigin: true,
        // rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    }
  },
```

and the api request calling something like a websocket once app is loaded:

```
getTenantInfo() {
    return api.get('http://foo.example.st/api/auth/...')
  }
```

this function is called once the App page is loaded. I've tried to setup on my `docker-compose.yml` a network config "bridge" but still not working:

docker-compose error log:

```
   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
front_1  |   ➜  Network: http://[ip_address]:5173/
front_1  | 7:35:01 PM [vite] http proxy error at /api/auth/...:
front_1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
front_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
```

I would appreciate for a help or advice